# Не понимаю разницу между signed / unsigned

Tags: c, signed, unsigned

Не понимаю разницу между `signed` и `unsigned`, читал много материала в интернете, но вот как-то не получается понять. Зачем используют в коде эти ключевые слова и что они дают?

На одном из сайтов написано:

> The term "unsigned" in computer programming indicates a variable that can hold only positive numbers.

Но ведь я могу сделать так:

```
unsigned int x = -100;
```

И компилятор не выдаст ошибку, то есть беззнаковый всё таки может хранить отрицательное значение? Или я что-то упустил? Все объяснения в интернете уходит сразу в `-127 to 127` и `0 to 256`, но это не дает мне понимания. Объясните, пожалуйста, русским языком.

Comment: для gcc/clang есть ключик `-Wconversion` - который подобные случаи поймает и поругает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL; DR**

Знаковые и беззнаковые типы имеют один и тот же размер, одни и те же требования выравнивания, а отличаются они в основном «смыслом» какого-то одного бита: у первых он означает знак числа, а у вторых — само значение.

> ```
> unsigned int x = -100;
> ```

Ошибку компилятор не выдает, потому что в C слабая типизация и `-100` неявно конверируется в `unsigned int`.

---

Для начала приведу несколько выдержек из стандарта (следует читать по-порядку):

> Существует пять **стандартных знаковых целочисленных типа**: `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int` и `long long int`. <…>
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:2017 § 6.2.5 / 4

> Для каждого такого знакового типа существует соответствующий беззнаковый тип, что обозначается ключевым словом `unsigned`. Этот тип имеет тот же *размер* (включая информацию о знаке) и *требования выравнивания*. <…>
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:2017 § 6.2.5 / 6

> Для любого беззнакового типа (кроме `unsigned char`), биты объектного представления делятся на две группы: *значимые биты* и *padding-биты*. Если в типе N значимых бит, то он должен быть способен представлять значения от 0 до 2<sup>N</sup> − 1 в двоичной системе счисления.
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:2017 § 6.2.6.2 / 1

> Для любого знакового типа биты объектного представления делятся на три группы: *значимые биты*, *padding-биты* и *знаковый бит*. В любом типе должен быть всего один знаковый бит. <…> Если он равен нулю, то результирующее значение не меняется. Если же он равен единице, значение должно быть модифицированно одним из следующих способов:
>
> - соответствующее значение с нулевым знаковым битом инвертируется (sign and magnitude);
> - знаковый бит имеет значение −(2<sup>M</sup>) (two's complement);
> - знаковый бит имеет значение —(2<sup>M</sup> − 1) (one's complement).
>
> <…>
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:2017 § 6.2.6.2 / 2

---

Таким образом отличие знаковых типов от беззнаковых заключается, собственно, в бите знака: в первых он есть, а во вторых — нет.

> И компилятор не выдаст ошибку, то есть беззнаковый всё таки может
> хранить отрицательное значение?

Нет, беззнаковое число не может хранить отрицательное значение, потому что в нем нет бита знака. А ошибку компилятор не выдает, потому что выполняется неявное преобразование `-100` в тип `unsigned int`.

Мы можем присвоить вещественное число переменной типа `int`:

```
int a = 3.14;
```

Но это ведь не значит, что переменные типа `int` могут хранить дробные значения?

Answer (score 4):

Разница в том, что при для знаковых и беззнаковых чисел процессор использует разные операторы для умножения, деления и сравнения на больше/меньше.

Например, для большинства платформ `signed char(-1)` и `unsigned char(255)` имеют в памяти представление `0xFF`

Но `signed char(0xFF) < 127`, а `unsigned char(0xFF) > 127`

`signed char(0xFF) * 100 = -100`, а `unsigned char(0xFF) * 100 = 25500`

И так далее

Comment: `signed char(0xFF)` не скомпилируется.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat проверил в gcc, компилируется, только предупреждение кидает

Comment: @andreymal Хм, а у меня ошибка: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Thz3Gj

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а, ну в таком синтаксисе и `signed char(-1)` ведь тоже не компилируется, а вот какой-нибудь `signed char a=(0xFF)` вполне компилируется

Comment: @andreymal Угу, я просто первый попавшийся каст взял. Надо было точнее выразиться.

Answer (score 2):

тип `int` может принимать значения от −2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 (или от –32768 до 32767), а
тип `unsigned int` может принимать значения от 0 до 4 294 967 295 (или от 0 до 65535)

действительно, вы можете сделать так:

```cpp
unsigned int x = -100;
```

но тогда произойдёт [переполнение](https://ravesli.com/urok-31-tselochislennyj-tip-dannyh-integer/#toc-4). Рассмотрим пример (тип short занимает 16 бит):

```cpp
unsigned short x = 65535; // наибольшее значение, которое может хранить 16-битная unsigned переменная
std::cout << "x was: " << x << std::endl;
x = x + 1; // 65536 - это число больше максимально допустимого числа из диапазона допустимых значений. Следовательно, произойдёт переполнение, так как переменнная x не может хранить 17 бит
std::cout << "x is now: " << x << std::endl;
```

Вывод:

```
x was: 65535
x is now: 0
```

Что случилось? Произошло переполнение, так как мы попытались присвоить переменной x значение больше, чем она способна в себе хранить.

Число 65 535 в двоичной системе счисления представлено как 1111 1111 1111 1111. 65 535 — это наибольшее число, которое может хранить 2-байтовая (16 бит) целочисленная переменная без знака, так как это число использует все 16 бит. Когда мы добавляем 1, то получаем число 65 536. Число 65 536 представлено в двоичной системе как 1 0000 0000 0000 0000, и занимает 17 бит! Следовательно, самый главный бит (которым является 1) теряется, а все 16 бит справа — остаются. Комбинация 0000 0000 0000 0000 соответствует десятичному 0, что и является нашим результатом.

Comment: переполнение возникает в результате вычисления, у вас для `unsigned int x = -100` вычисление не производится, только инициализация, но это не точно

Comment: @Cerbo беззнаковые числа вообще не переполняются по определению.

Comment: @Croessmah Как вы это себе представляете? Где вы такое определение видели? Все типы с фиксированной шириной "умеют" переполняться

Comment: @tutankhamun например, об этом явно написано в стандарте языка: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2

Comment: @Croessmah Какая жуть. Не думал что C++ до такого доведут. Но я что-то не пойму. Две фразы вроде как друг-другу противоречат: 1) arithmetic for the unsigned type is performed modulo 2^N 2) Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow

Comment: @tutankhamun нет, не противоречат. Нужно учитывать, что в русском языке почему-то перенос или заем тоже называются переполнением. Но ведь переполнением считается именно overflow, который имеет смысл только для операций со знаковыми. Если происходит заем или перенос, то это совершенно другая ситуация и вот именно она имеет смысл для беззнаковых чисел. В C++ 
 перенос просто игнорируется и получается арифметика по модулю 2^N

Comment: @tutankhamun к слову, это так всегда было и даже в  C89 тоже так, поэтому ваше "до такого доведут" не ясно.

Comment: @Croessmah Похоже тут дело в терминологии. Как-то не попадалась мне раньше фраза что для беззнаковых переполнение не характерно